# ipod touch 2nd generation issues ui overlapping

Tags: iphone, ios5, arm, ipod

I was facing issues in ipod touch devices when build with ios 5. It actually messes up the entire screen and all the textbox, labels, buttons displayed in the bottom of the screen and after scrolling up and down, everything gets aligned properly.

I have same issue in iphone, i just did the following setting and it did worked with same ios sdk (armv6armv7, with no optimization level none).

Have you guys faced similar issues ? iPod touch 2nd generation is the only problem now. Do you have any suggestions for fixing this up ?

or is this a ios problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the same changes as you to solve it.  Just make sure you also change it for Distribution and Release too (I made that mistake).

As for the iPod touch 2G - that doesn't support iOS 5. Are you looking specifically about supporting iOS 5 on an iPod touch 2G?  If so, according to Apple, you don't have to.